# php script to read csv file to json with static header before items

Tags: php, json, csv

this is my CSV data

| Shulename | Shuleid | systemTransId | transactionDate | sttId | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mzimu | 01-022-1 | 20-007440 | 18/05/2021 | 12 | F |
| mzimu | 01-022-1 | 20-007441 | 18/05/2021 | 13 | M |
| mzimu | 01-022-1 | 20-007442 | 19/05/2021 | 14 | M |

This is my expected results

```json
{
   "shulename": "mzimu",
   "shuleid": "01-022-1",
   "items": 
  [
         {
           "systemTransId": "20-007440",
           "transactionDate": "18/05/2021",
           "sttId": "12",
           "gender": "F"
         },
         {
           "systemTransId": "20-007441",
           "transactionDate": "18/05/2021",
           "sttId": "13",
           "gender": "M"

         },
         {
           "systemTransId": "20-007442",
           "transactionDate": "19/05/2021",
           "sttId": "14",
           "gender": "M"

         }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Do you have more than one `shulename` or is it always `mzimu`? Also what have you tried so far? Are you able to read the csv into php?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: yes Shulename and shuleid will never change

Comment: Im able to read csv but the arrangement is not the one I want 
that static header (shuleid,shulename) they join the data

Comment: @Kinglish 
i want a cript that can make json data from csv file but in that format

Comment: Can you post your code where you read the file into php

Comment: @endeavour 
<?php
if (($handle = fopen('revenue.csv', 'r')) === false) {
    die('Error opening file');
}

$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
$complete = array();

while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',')) {
    $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
}

fclose($handle);

echo json_encode($complete);
?>

Comment: You should use single backtick for inline codes and three backticks when posting a code block to make the codes readable. Check formatting hints when you edit or write a comment or question

Comment: @endeavour
```<?php
if (($handle = fopen('revenue.csv', 'r')) === false) {
    die('Error opening file');
}

$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
$complete = array();

while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',')) {
    $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
}

fclose($handle);

echo json_encode($complete);
?>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a working demo of it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/400X1OR0vepmj7o6

I faked the csv stream to show how to use this with `fgetcsv`

```
$csv = "Shulename,Shuleid,systemTransId,transactionDate,sttId,gender
mzimu,01-022-1,20-007440,18/05/2021,12,F
mzimu,01-022-1,20-007441,18/05/2021,13,M
mzimu,01-022-1,20-007442,19/05/2021,14,M";

//$file = fopen("YOURFILE.csv","r");

$file     = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $csv,'r');
$line = 0 ;
$keys = [];
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
{
   if ($line==0) {
       // set up the array
       foreach ($data as $d) $keys[]=strtolower($d);
       
       $output = array(
           $keys[0] => "", 
           $keys[1] => "",
           "items" => array()
           );
   } else {
        if ($line==1) {
            $output[$keys[0]] = $data[0];
            $output[$keys[1]] = $data[1];
        }
        $tmp = [];
        for ($x=2; $x<count($keys); $x++) {
            $tmp[$keys[$x]] = $data[$x];
        }   
        $output['items'][]=$tmp;
   }
   $line++;
}

$output = json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


die("<pre>".print_r($output,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment and if I understand it correctly `shulename` will always be `mzimu` and `shuleid` will always be `01-022-1`.

Hence continuing from what you wrote the codes to create the format you want is

```php
if (($handle = fopen('revenue.csv', 'r')) === false) {
    die('Error opening file');
}
$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
$complete = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',')) {
    $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
}
fclose($handle);

// We have shulename and shuleid assigned statically
// because you said they will always be the same

$requiredFormat = ['shulename' => 'mzimu',
    'shuleid' => '01-022-1'];
foreach ($complete as $item) {
    ## Notice the case here. The csv in the question is ucfirst and the required format is lower case
    ## php indexes are case sensitive
    unset($item['Shulename']);
    unset($item['Shuleid']);
    $requiredFormat['items'][] = $item;
}
echo json_encode($requiredFormat);
```